# Is Emacs using a TAGS file to locate built-in definitions?

Tags: builtin

Out of the box, my emacs build can jump to elisp function definitions. For example, I start emacs with no init file, type `copy-to-buffer` in the scratch buffer, hit `M-.`, and it opens up simple.el.gz with the cursor on the defun for `copy-to-buffer`.

I would think this indicates there's a TAGS file somewhere that emacs is using, but I can't locate it. I checked the values of `tags-file-name` and `tags-table-list`, both of which are nil.

I searched the directory where emacs is installed (I installed with Homebrew),

```
find /usr/local/Cellar/ -iname *tags*
```

and found nothing on interest. I searched all of `/usr/` as well.

What black magic is this? Does Emacs have some kind of internalized tags table for the built-in elisp libraries?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. `emacs -Q` for emacs24.5, type in a function name and hit `M-.` and I get prompted for a tag, and then a tags table. However the `find-function-at-point`  function does what you describe.

Comment: Emacs does have internal information on where functions are defined, and  doesn't use an external tag table.

Comment: @icarus I should have specified, my description is of the behavior when running emacs in a gui. If run in a terminal, I see the same as you -- `M-.` prompts for a tag, but `find-function-at-point` works automatically. Is there any documentation confirming/describing the presence of this internal information? I wasn't able to find anything. I tried crawling through source code as well, though I didn't get very far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't use a TAGS file, or even the same code that works with TAGS files. Instead, any time you load an elisp file (using `require` or `load` or similar) Emacs stores information about the symbols that are defined in that file in a variable called `load-history`. You can see its contents with `C-h v load-history RET`, and you can read the source code that uses it with `C-h k M-.` and following the link to the definition of the function `xref-find-definitions`. Burrow down a few levels and you'll find `elisp--xref-find-definitions` which calls `find-lisp-object-file-name` which calls `symbol-file` which looks the info up in `load-history`.

Edit: I just saw your comment about Emacs 24; I'm describing Emacs 25. In earlier versions it wasn't as unified.

Comment: n.b. The `xref` behaviour and `M-.` global binding was introduced in Emacs 25.1. (`find-function` and friends have been present for a very long time, OTOH.)

Answer (score 1):

Internally emacs stores this information on the `load-history` variable.

A small part of it might look like

```
(("the/file/name.el" var1 var2 (defun . fn1) (defun . fn2))
 ("ano/ther/filename.el" var3 var4 (defun . fn3))
 ... )
```

to record 4 variables and 3 functions. I think once it has the filename it just searches for the name.